# Is there a way to view past pictures that you have drawn? 

Tags: draw-something

I was playing and I did a drawing I thought was pretty good. Is there any way to go back without taking a screenshot before hitting done?

I have another chance when I watch them back during the video of them guessing. I was hoping to find out before I lose out on that chance.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No... but soon you will be able to with the next update .

> You’ll  be able to save your drawings to your device’s photo library (a feature that was requested by many users). As of now, Draw Something doesn’t have a save option, meaning that your “masterpieces” are forever lost with each new round. Sure, you can take screenshots (which many people did), but not everyone can do this and not on every phone. The save drawing option is probably one of the best features that are being added into the game.

http://www.androidauthority.com/draw-something-update-new-features-67796/

Comment: Thank you both. I update is good to hear, and obviously I am not the only one that is in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that I have found to date with out just snapping the picture at the appropriate time when you are either done drawing or they have guessed the picture.